# User and Item relationship modeling with type of actions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I have `User` and `Item` models. User may `like`, `want` or `own` items. How can i create this relationships in rails? This three actions may increase in future so I want to make it flexible.

*sorry for my english*

UPDATE

I created models named `UserAction` and `UserActionType`

in **user.rb** i added

```
has_many :user_actions
has_many :actions, :through => :user_actions, :source => :user_action

def method_missing(method_id, *arguments)
    if match = /([_a-zA-Z]\w*)_it/.match(method_id.to_s)
      action_name = match[1]
      action_type = UserActionType.find_by_name(action_name)
      action = action_type.user_actions.new
      action.user = self
      action.item = arguments[0]

      action_type.save
      action.save

    elsif match = /find_my_([_a-zA-Z]\w*)s/.match(method_id.to_s)
      action_name = match[1]
      user_actions.joins('LEFT JOIN user_action_types ON user_action_types.id = user_actions.user_action_type_id').where('user_action_types.name = "'+ action_name +'"')
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

In this way, i have methods like `own_it`, `want_it`, `like_it` and `find_my_likes`, `find_my_*` etc.

What do you think about my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) for each *action*. To create several `has_and_belongs_to_many` relations between `User` and `Item`, you'll have to user the `class_name` option :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :liked_items, :class_name => 'Item'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :wanted_items, :class_name => 'Item'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :owned_items, :class_name => 'Item'

  #...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think is better you use a [through-association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association).

So, you will have a model between your User and Item model, like user_item where you can storage a type (like, want or own).

I dont think you need another model to control types (like, want or own), look this gem [Ambry](https://github.com/norman/ambry). With it you can create a "virtual db".

Good luck!